# Error when "orb.detectAndCompute" when using opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv, orb

I am trying to use ORB to find the keypoints and descriptors of previously generated spectrograms. I have this code:

```
start = time.time()
x = 1
img = range(101)
imgname = range(101)

# Directory Images
os.chdir("/home/undead/Documents/TempSongSpectro/") #1,2,3
for file in glob.glob("*.png"):
    img[x] = cv2.imread(file, 0)  # trainImage
    imgname[x] = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
# print "%s: %d " % (os.path.splitext(file)[0],(x))
x = x + 1

# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create(3000)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
a = 1
des = range(101)
kp = range(101)

for a in range(1, 101):
    kp[a], des[a] = orb.detectAndCompute(img[a], None)

end = time.time()
print("Initialize time: %f seconds" % (end - start))
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F) in cvtColor, file /home/undead/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9710

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/undead/PycharmProjects/KavTest/Test3.py", line 37, in <module>
    kp[a], des[a] = orb.detectAndCompute(img[a], None)

cv2.error: /home/undead/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9710: error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor
```

From what i gathered, the error may be related to the datatype of kp, des or img, but I'm not too sure on how to solve it. Can someone offer some assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong in your code.

This is my code doing nearly the same.

```
start = time.time()

imgnames = glob.glob("/home/undead/Documents/TempSongSpectro/*.png")
#imgnames = imgnames[:100]

sz = len(imgnames)
imgs = list(range(sz))

for i, name in enumerate(imgnames, start=0):
    imgs[i] =  cv2.imread(name, 0)

orb = cv2.ORB_create(3000)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
des = list(range(sz))
kp = list(range(sz))

for i in range(sz):
    kp[i], des[i] = orb.detectAndCompute(img[i], None)

end = time.time()
print("Initialize time: {:.4f} seconds".format(end - start))
```